# 'Unupvote' rewording

Tags: feature-request, wording, undo

I'd like to see the SE term "unupvote" be changed to an actual word.  This may seem like petty pedantry, [but I thought we were a little different to other Q&A sites?](https://stackexchange.com/tour).  Let's at least make things make sense.

Some suggestions:

- undo
- un-upvote
- upvote undo

Comment: [Undo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/215468/undo) is already a user so we can't use that...

Comment: @rene But my suggestion is not capitalized...

Comment: Sorry, but why exactly does "un-upvote" make sense but the non(-)hyphenated version doesn't? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There no reason to change this in my opinion. The word "unupvote" is fine and this is very minor.

I have never used the other words suggested.

> but I thought we were a little different to other Q&A sites?

That is in the way we function and how we give feedback by voting and reviewing, not by using complicated English. We’re the same in using words people commonly use and understand.

> - undo

- A [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/215468/undo) as pointed out
- Not clear, undo what?

> - un-upvote

- Longer to type (by a bit)
- Does a hyphen make a difference?

> - upvote undo

- Unnecessary wording, "unupvote" is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by *"We’re the same in..."* E.g., same as what? What are you trying to say in that paragraph? Perhaps rephrase it?

Comment: Upvoting undo for posts he didn't post seems like a bug